# Parameters not working, what's wrong here

Tags: c#, .net

The insert message not working!
I trying to insert data by using parameters

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The variable name '@name' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.'

```
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();


    
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //save | event Click
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



        if (txtName.Text == "" || txtLocation.Text == "")
        {
               MessageBox.Show("no data!","Hey you...",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        else

        {
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "insert into Table_1 values ( @name ,@location )";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", txtLocation.Text);
            con.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
        

    }

    //clear fun
    private void Clear()

    {
        txtName.Clear();
        txtLocation.Clear();
    }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please explain why you think “parameters not working”.

Comment: Please read [ask] and follow the tips there for what makes a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a scope issue.  You define the SqlCommand `com` outside of the scope where you modify it (ie- add to the parameters list).  Essentially you are adding the `@name` parameter each time your `btnSave_Click` method is called.

Move the line where you create `com` into the method so it looks like this:

```
 SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
 com.Connection = con;
 com.CommandText = "insert into Table_1 values ( @name ,@location )";
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", txtLocation.Text);
 con.Open();
 com.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

And remove `SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();` from the top of the code.

This way the command gets recreated every time the method runs, and when it gets recreated the parameters list will be empty and the lines where you add the parameters won't fail.

**EDIT**
To further clarify - The issue is that when you define it where you do, then you only should add the parameters once.  As a "global variable" (actually, in your code it's called a field) such as you're creating it only gets instantiated once, which is fine.  The problem arises when you add parameters to the SqlCommand.  Because that button click handler runs each time (I assume) a button is clicked you are repeatedly adding the parameters to the list.  The first time you click the button is ok, because the parameters list is empty at that time.  The next time you click the button you will get the exception because that list already has those parameters added.

If you want to continue to use `cmd` as a global variable / field then you should clear the parameters list in your handler method like this:

```
 com.Connection = con;
 com.CommandText = "insert into Table_1 values ( @name ,@location )";
 com.Parameters.clear();
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
 com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", txtLocation.Text);
 con.Open();
 com.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

Comment: SqlConnection must be used in a using block, or be disposed at the end of the method.

Comment: @Oscar while it's good (best) practice, it's not required.

Comment: thanks @squillman
could you give me more explanation.
I was add    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();   as global variable so I can access it from anywhere. so what's the issue here

Comment: @squillman
is it important to add con.open(); in the 1st line of scope or can I put it anywhere inside the scope, sorting is important?

Comment: @Mohamed See my edit.  And regarding opening and closing the connection, that's a whole separate topic.  I can't really say what the best thing for you to do here.  It depends on a lot of other things like network and how you have other pieces of your code structured.

Comment: @squillman Disposing objects is more than a best practice, as not doing so will lead to memory leaks in your application.

Comment: @Oscar No real argument in general, but here it's managed code so the garbage collector will pick it up.  It is definitely best practice by and large and required in certain circumstances, but with SqlConnection there are times when you intentionally reuse an instance in which case you don't want to wrap it in a `using{}` and you dispose of it elsewhere.  It is a good habit to get into, but you should know when and when not to use it.

Comment: @squillman No, GC can't pick up unmanaged objects created by managed classes, that's why it's your responsibility to call Dispose(). If it were that simple, then it woudn't make sense to ask programmers to call Dispose(), as GC eventually would clean it up by itself. About reusing connections, I personally consider it a code smell, and probably a violation of the Single Responsibility principle.

Comment: @Oscar That was my point.  SqlConnection is managed code.  Your point definitely resonates for something like a COM object.  And, the fact that SqlConnection CAN hold an instance of something that is not managed code behind the scenes does make `using` a best practice because you're right - in that case the connection won't get picked up by the GC and you'll have a memory leak.  I don't disagree with you that reusing connections can be a code smell.  So, while `using` is best practice it's not required, and I'll add "as long as you know what you're doing!"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring Connection as a class variable, make it a local variable inside the click handler and put it in a using block. Currently you're adding the same parameter on every button click.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection()){
   //your code here
}
```